# ng-click "id (factory)" going to new template but not shows img from specific id

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I can go to id position (http://localhost:9000/#/info-serie/1) using `ng-click`, but without show img of the id, I was try with this information http://jsfiddle.net/daSJ5/124/, but nothing.

```
$scope.sliderImg = slider.getsliderImg();
$scope.go = function(id){
      $location.url('/info-serie/' + id);
};
//////////////// VIEW ONE //////////////////////////
<div ng-repeat="images in sliderImg" ng-click="go(images.id)">
    <img ng-src="{{images.img}}" alt="" class="img-carousel"/>
</div>
//////////////// VIEW TWO //////////////////////////
<img ng-src="{{images.img}}" alt=""/>

'use strict';

angular.module('appApp').factory('slider', function(){
        var sliderImg = [
                {
                    id  : 0,
                    img : "../../images/American-Horror-Story-season-4.jpg"
                },
                {
                    id  : 1,
                    img : "../../images/Defiance-season-3-2015.jpg"
                },
                {
                    id  : 2,
                    img : "../../images/Falling_Skies_poster_the_fianl_season.jpg"
                }
            ];
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you wanted to say?

Comment: I want go to img id in new template. 
http://localhost:9000/#/info-serie/2, 2=id show img of this id using {{images.img}}. Look this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/daSJ5/124/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understood your problem but from watching the code a few remarks

factory needs to return something (by the look of your service it seems like you just created a variable.

one more thing is the url. if you want to change the url it's ok  but if you wanna change a page and not only url you should probably try $location.path('/info-serie/' + id).

hope this helps

Comment: Yes, return it. return {
   getsliderImg: function() {
    return sliderImg;
   }
  };

Comment: I have a slider, if I do click any img it go to id, and "it have to show id img".
click --> go to id --> it id have img (show).